# How to import a component from another OpenAPI file?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Can you import a component that is defined in an other OpenAPI file?
Suppose I have two openAPI files:
`openAPI.yaml` and `otherOpenAPI.yaml`.
In `openAPI.yml` I want to use the `myItem` component that is defined in `otherOpenAPI.yaml`

Can I do something in the likes of:
`$ref: './otherOpenAPI.yaml/components/myItem` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

`$ref: './otherOpenApi.yaml#/components/MyItem'`